# run some tests only in specific environment

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

I am writing some tests which only make sense in a specific environment, e.g. if the host has a Nvidia CUDA capable GPU, or maybe it depends on other resources which are specific to some environment.

How can I specify that with Nosetests? My optimum would be if Nosetests would list the skipped tests and the reason for the skips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it generally with standard [unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) library. At the very start of your tests you can always check for prerequisites [with decorators](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures) (preferred) or by raising [SkipTest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.SkipTest) exception.

```
import unittest 

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @unittest.skipIf(not have_gpu(),
                     "no gpu on this system")
    def test_gpu_performance(self):
        pass

    def test_something_else(self):
        if not have_gpu():
            raise unittest.SkipTest("no gpu")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [tag tests](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html) with the `@attr` decorator from `nose.plugins.attrib` that you want to run only if a given attribute is set.

```py
@attr(has_cuda_gpu=1)
def test_something(self):
    pass
```

Then create a test runner script that configures these attributes. If your conditions are met, add those attributes:

```sh
ATTRS="some_other_condition=1"
if [ check_cuda_gpu ]; then
    ATTRS="$ATTRS,has_cuda_gpu=1"
fi
nosetests -a $ATTRS
```

When you run your tests, and `has_cud_gpu` was not added to the attributes, then those tests decorated with this condition will be skipped.

Comment: Is there some way to test the condition also in Python itself, maybe have that in the test code? Something like: `if not have_gpu(): raise CannotTest("no gpu")` or so.

Comment: I don't know if there is a python library to do that, but you can always make system calls from python ;)